# How to delete text from a JTextField when you press a JButton (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing

My program has to print messages in the `JTextField` when the Resume Producers button is pressed, and it needs to delete the messages when the Resume Consumers is pressed.

The thing is that I don't know how to delete the messages when the Resume Consumers is pressed.

[image: The problem]

Code:

```
    package buffer;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Buffer
    {
        private String message;
        private boolean full=false;
        Topass pass = new Topass();
        public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
        JTextField tf;
        String content="";

        public Buffer(JTextField t1){
            tf=t1;
        }   

        public synchronized void put(String message)
        {
            list.add(message);

        }

        public synchronized void take(String message)
        {
            list.remove(message);

        }

        public synchronized void sendMessage(String msg)
        {
           while(full && list.size()>=30)
                {
                try
                {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {   }
                }
                pass.look();
                full=true;
                message=msg;
                list.add(message);
                for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                    content=content+list.get(i);
                }
                tf.setText(content);
                notifyAll();

            }




        public synchronized String receivesMessage()
        {       

                while(!full)
            {
                try
                {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {   }
            }
            pass.look();
            full=false;
            notifyAll();
            return message;        
            }

    }


package buffer;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Consumer extends Thread
{

    private int numMessages;
    private Buffer miBuffer;
    private String readers;

    public Consumer(String reader, Buffer miBuffer)
    {

        this.numMessages=numMessages;
        this.miBuffer=miBuffer;
        this.readers=reader;
    }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true){
             try
            {
                sleep((int)(300+400*Math.random()));
            } catch(InterruptedException e){ }
            System.out.println(readers + " Has read " + miBuffer.receivesMessage());

        }





    }
}


    package buffer;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Producer extends Thread
{
    private String prefix;
    private int numMessages;
    private Buffer miBuffer;



    public Producer(String prefix, int n, Buffer buffer)
    {
        this.prefix=prefix;
        numMessages=n;
        miBuffer=buffer;
    }



    public void run()
    {
        numMessages = 99;
        for(int i=1; i<=numMessages; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                sleep((int)(500+400*Math.random()));
            } catch(InterruptedException e){  }
        miBuffer.sendMessage(prefix+i);



            //miBuffer.meter(prefijo+i);

        }
    }
}





    package buffer;


public class Topass
{
    private boolean closed=false;

    public synchronized void look()
    {
        while(closed)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException ie){ }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void open()
    {
        closed=false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void closed()
    {
        closed=true;
    }
}




    package buffer;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.ArrayBufferView.buffer;

/**
 *
 * @author Bogdan
 */
public class DigitalBuffer extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    Buffer buffer;
    Producer p;
    Consumer c;
    Topass paso = new Topass();


    /**
     * Creates new form BufferGrafico
     */
    public DigitalBuffer() {
        initComponents();
        buffer = new Buffer(t1);
        Producer A = new Producer("A",99,buffer);
        Producer B = new Producer("B",99,buffer);
        Producer C = new Producer("C",99,buffer);
        Producer D = new Producer("D",99,buffer);
        Consumer Luis = new Consumer("LUIS", buffer);
        Consumer Juan = new Consumer("JUAN", buffer);
        Consumer Maria = new Consumer("MARIA", buffer);
        Consumer Ana = new Consumer ("ANA", buffer);
        A.start();
        B.start();
        C.start();
        D.start();
        Luis.start();
        Juan.start();
        Maria.start();
        Ana.start();

    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        t1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        JButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        t1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                t1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Buffer content");

        JButton1.setText("Stop Producers");
        JButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JButton2.setText("Resume Producers");
        JButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JButton3.setText("Stop Consumers");
        JButton3.addAncestorListener(new javax.swing.event.AncestorListener() {
            public void ancestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
                JButton3AncestorAdded(evt);
            }
            public void ancestorRemoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
                JButton3AncestorRemoved(evt);
            }
            public void ancestorMoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
            }
        });
        JButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JButton4.setText("Resume Consumers");
        JButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(t1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 306, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                        .addComponent(JButton1)
                        .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                        .addComponent(JButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(102, 102, 102))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(104, 104, 104)
                        .addComponent(JButton3)
                        .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                        .addComponent(JButton4)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(t1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(JButton1)
                    .addComponent(JButton2))
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(JButton3)
                    .addComponent(JButton4))
                .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void t1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

    }                                  

    private void JButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        buffer.pass.closed();

    }                                        

    private void JButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            buffer.pass.open();

    }                                        

    private void JButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        buffer.pass.closed();
    }                                        

    private void JButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }                                        

    private void JButton3AncestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void JButton3AncestorRemoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DigitalBuffer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DigitalBuffer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DigitalBuffer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DigitalBuffer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DigitalBuffer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton JButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton JButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton JButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton JButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField t1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It should not take over 400 lines across 5 public classes to express this problem! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: `Sorry if my code is to messy, im just in my second year of university.` - you should be able to write well formatted code after 15 minutes of using Java. For example, Indentation of code blocks should be consistent, single blank lines used for spacing.  This does not take any programming skill.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that i don't know how to delete the messages when the Resume Consumers is pressed

You add an ActionListener to the button. In the ActionListener you reset the text. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Us Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and examples. Or, there is also a section on `How to Write an ActionListener`.

You can replace the text in the text field by using:

```
textField.setText(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example #1 (Requires Java 8+):

```
button.addActionListener(e -> textField.setText(""));
```

Example #2:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField.setText("");
    }
});
```

In both cases, the textField will need to have been declared as *final*.